# paginate by a number of objects django

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-pagination

So pagination isn't working even without initiating django-filters from templates, I'm not able to paginate by the number of objects I want, it's showing all of them at once

*Note: I'm not saying both should work together(pagination and django-filter), just that I wanna fix the pagination

views.py

```
def music_page(request):

    #pagination & filter

    music = Music.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    music_filter = MusicFilter(request.GET, queryset=music)
    paginator = Paginator(music, 6)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    try:
        music = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        music = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        music.paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, template_name='main/music.html', context={'music': music, 'page_obj': page_obj, 'filter': music_filter})
```

template

```
<div class='card'>
    {% for m in filter.qs %}
        <div class='year'>{{m.Year}}</div>
        <div class='song_name'>{{m.song}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are not passing in the correct queryset. You need to pass in the filtered queryset instead of music.

```
music = Music.objects.all().order_by('-id')
music_filter = MusicFilter(request.GET, queryset=music)

filtered_music = music_filter.qs
paginator = Paginator(filtered_music, 6)
```

Then in your template you have to loop through this `page_obj` in order to get your objects.

```
<div class='card'>
    {% for m in page_obj %}
        <div class='year'>{{m.Year}}</div>
        <div class='song_name'>{{m.song}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```